# Constructing new dataframe from mixture of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame organised with the following headers. I am only interested in weeknum 2 and 3. I would like a new data frame, maintaining everything from Year Group to Weeknum, but replacing the final two columns with "Lates WK2", "Lates WK3", "Negs WK2", Negs WK3". I.e. only one row per student with this information.  How can I construct this?

```
Year Group Class                   Student  ... Weeknum  Lates  Negs
0          7.0    7G            Stud 1          ...       1      4   4.0

1          7.0    7G            Stud 1          ...       2      5   9.0

2          7.0    7G            Stud 1          ...       3      8   6.0
....

17         7.0    7G            Stud n          ...       1      7   3.0

18         7.0    7G            Stud n          ...       2      6   5.0

19         7.0    7G            Stud n          ...       3      3   2.0
```

Comment: use `df.query('Weeknum > 1').pivot(index = ['Year Group', 'Class','Student'], columns = 'Weeknum')`